# Which activation function should I use for this Neural Network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

We are developing a neural network for Checkers game. In our training data,

0 represents blank cell,
1 represents white piece,
-1 represents white king,
2 represents black piece and
-2 represents black king

So, what we need is an activation function withing range [-2, 2]. Which activation function should we use? Please give your suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Is your input in [-2, 2] or the output? The input of logistic sigmoid can be arbitrary. Also your encoding is maybe not optimal for ANNs.

Comment: Both are in the given range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see reason why you couldn't use sigmoid function
[image: Sigmoid function]

Range of sigmoid function is [0, 1] 
To modify sigmoid function to fit your needs, you can multiply it by 4, multiplying function by a constant affect it's amplitude ( Range  = [0, 4] ), 
and than subtract 2, with subtracting / adding you can move function on Y-axis ( Range = [-2, 2] ) 
So the function would look like this: 
S(t) = 4* ( 1 / (1 + e ^ (-t)) ) - 2

Answer (score 3):

Your state encoding is not optimal. Usually neural networks work better with [1-of-c encoding](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-7.html) for categories. Then, it is easy to use sigmoid units. Just take the argmax of the 5 outputs to determine the state.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! sigmoid function works well since it neatly fits into the range you have specified. I also use it for a pattern recognition problem i am developing. Linear tends to work well.